# How to add multiple callbacks to rolify gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, rolify

According to rolify gem documentation.
This gem adds the rolify method to your User class. You can also specify optional callbacks on the User class for when roles are added or removed:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify :before_add => :before_add_method

  def before_add_method(role)
    # do something before it gets added
  end
end
```

The rolify method accepts the following callback options:

```
before_add
after_add
before_remove
after_remove
```

Mongoid callbacks are also supported and works the same way.

when i add multiple callbacks to rolify it only works for last one
my code

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify :before_add => :before_add_method
  rolify :before_remove => :before_remove_method

  private

  def before_add_method(role)
  #to do
  end
  def before_remove_method(role)
  #to do
  end
end
```

only before_remove_method method called.
Any suggestion how we can add multiple callbacks to rolify gem?

Answer (score 6):

i found the solution.
actually we need to pass each callbacks separated by , like below

```
rolify :before_add => :before_add_method, :before_remove => :before_remove_method
```